# HTML canvas recolour/edit a shape or array?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am building a real-time canvas clicking game, and am almost complete.
I need to change the colour of a canvas drawn element. I hear this cannot be done.
I have a variable holding these properties of the clicked shape for use on both clients:

```
{ x: 446.48232363630086,
  y: 279.37327971844934,
  dx: 2.829614687943831,
  dy: -3.0215198849327862,
  rad: 26,
  color: 'rgb(146,25,122)' }
```

And I have another variable holding a new colour, if it is not possible to change the colour of a something drawn on the canvas, can I edit the object in the array which would make my current drawShape function redraw the changed shape? This is my old single player code for some reference.
https://jsfiddle.net/a9b3rm5u/5/ Thank you

Comment: Clear your canvas canvas.clearRect(x,y,dx,dy) and redraw your shapes with new color

Comment: Similar to what you had in the single layer, you have to redraw most/all shapes because of overlays.  Simply clearing the x,y,dx,dy and redraw with new color may not work if there is another shape touching this area.

Comment: But if I change the shape in the array to have the new colour? then the other function should draw it with the new colour?

Comment: All drawings on canvas are unalterable. So to change a shape's style or position you must always erase the old shape (usually by clearing the entire canvas) and redraw the newly styled or positioned shape (by redrawing all the shapes).

Comment: but I am already redrawing the canvas, is it not possible to slice and push to the shapes array and let my current draw function deal with redrawing it once its in the array??

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
var i = data.shapeRemoval;//object data
var c = data.colours; // colour data
var r = c;
shapes.splice(i,1); // removes old object from array
i.color = c; // replaces the color in the object for the variable C
shapes.push(i)// pushes to array
```